# Numeric Matching with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

I am trying to perform a method  based on the matching of numerical vectors with uniform distribution. These vectors represent large integers, stoked(possible integer 64 in cpp11) consequently as a double and  for each `x` value between 0 and power(5, 20).
The match function will determine the first position of an element `xi` of a vector A into the vector B.
According to two different concepts, I use two methods:

First,a matching method already implemented which is based on hash tables which are very efficient for strings vectors.
I use the Match function with the following code as the template describes `Rcppsugar`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector Match(NumericVector A, NumericVector B) {  
    sugar::IndexHash<14> tab = wrap(A); 
    return tab.fill().lookup(B);
}
```

Thanks to `fastmatch` package, I use `fmatch` function that gives the best performance.

Otherwise, I think of a binary search process, but this method require  sorting witch is a big problem. The following code shows a prototype of the method used.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector sort_stl(NumericVector A) { 
    NumericVector tmp = clone(A);
    std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    return tmp;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector BINmatch(NumericVector A, NumericVector B) {// A and B previously sorted 
    const int a = A.size(); const int b = B.size();
    int j = 0; int i = 0;
    NumericVector res(a,-1.0);// empty values are coding with -1;
    for (i = i; i < a; i++) {
        for (j = j; (j < b) & (B[j] <= A[i]); j++) {
            if (B[j] == A[i]) {
                res[i] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

1. How can I perform the hash method to this situation?
2. How can I insert a key value before sorting to recover the position `xi` in the original vector?
3. How can I improve the sorting speed to the method `BINmatch`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem, but I suspect that it could help to have a look at `boost::bimap`.

Comment: Yes,I used also a sample std::map<key,value>, but  the code wasn't fast.

Comment: Do you know about [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and the general problem of comparing floating point for equality?

Comment: Thinks very much for this remark. The problem is not here  because used double variables have an integer origin. The problem is how can I spead up matching or sorting in this case.